# The useState is not being updated correctly in a loop

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, jspdf

I am working on a certificate generator, where I have a list of name and i want to ithrate through those name and display them on a certificate, then download that certificate as a pdf. And then I move on to the next name and so on.

```
const _exportPdf = async () => {

    // if namelist is not uploaded 
    if (nameList == null){
      console.log("Name List not uploaded");
      return;
    }

    // if name is uploaded 
    Object.keys(nameList).forEach(async function(key){
      const name = nameList[key];
      // export the certificate as a pdf 
      await html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => { 
        console.log("exporting "+name);
        setVisibleName(name);
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', "a4");
        const imgProps= pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
        var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        var height = (imgProps.height * width) / imgProps.width;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0,width, height);
        const filename = name + ".pdf";
        pdf.save(filename); 
    }) 
   });

  }
```

Currently I have 5 names in my sample nameList, when I use this function, I can see the name changeing on the certificate, but all the 5 downloaded certificates have "Sample Name" written on it (Sample Name is the default value of the visible name).

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in `forEach` async-await doesn't work, as you would expect. So use `for/ for of` instead.

Comment: I just tried for of, its not working,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using `forEach` within which promises don't work because the JS engine doesn't wait for the promise to be resolved/reject and instead puts the promise in a queue and continues executing the loop, secondly, you are using both `await` and `then` to resolve/reject the same promise.
Either, use `.then` syntax or `await` syntax.

```
const names = Object.keys(nameList)
for(name of names){
      // export the certificate as a pdf 
        const canvas = await html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")) //Wait for the promise to resolve/reject. Recommend to wrap it in try-catch block to handle errors.
        console.log("exporting "+name);
        setVisibleName(name);
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', "a4");
        const imgProps= pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
        var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        var height = (imgProps.height * width) / imgProps.width;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0,width, height);
        const filename = name + ".pdf";
        pdf.save(filename); 
}
```

Also, you haven't mentioned, where and how exactly are you making use of the state variable, but most likely you would've gotten the wrong result due to the incorrect usage of promises. Remember updates in the state cause the component to re-render.